# Firefox 4 giving a "couldn't calculate the application directory" error

Tags: firefox, installation

I'm installing Firefox 4 on my work's managed linux system, so I can't access the package manager.

I downloaded the Firefox 4 tar from their website and unpacked it into my home directory as per the instructions given [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Installing%20Firefox%20on%20Linux) which say to unpack the tar into `~`, which gives the directory `~/firefox`.

After doing this run the firefox script as `~/firefox/firefox`. When I do this I get the error message:

```
Couldn't calculate the application directory.
```

Has anyone else experienced this. It worked ok with the Firefox RC2 that I've just tried replacing.

Comment: I've got the same problem, but with thunderbird rather than firefox.

Comment: If you are still having this problem, are you running a 32 bit version of linux? If so, is it possible that your home directory is on a filesystem with 64 bit inodes?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem on Fedora Linux 10 by adding the directory that contains the firefox binary to the PATH environment variable.